# How do I send the data from one div to another?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am making some sort of shopping application, I'm now working on a functionality that adds the clicked product to the `checkoutList`. However, when a certain product is pressed, no data is sent and I'm just getting an 'undefined' back. I have made service named messenger.service.ts, that contains the function that's added to the button:

```
export class MessengerService {
  subject = new Subject()

  constructor() {}

  sendMsg(product) {
    console.log(product)
    this.subject.next(product) // triggering an event
  }

  getMsg() {
    return this.subject.asObservable()
  }
}
```

The product list, the component that contains the products that can be added to the `checkoutList`:

```
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {
  productList: Product[] = [];

  @Input() productItem: Product;

  constructor(private productService: ProductService, private msg: MessengerService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.productList = this.productService.getProducts();
  }

  onAddToCheckoutList() {
    this.msg.sendMsg(this.productItem);
  }
}
```

The component that listens to the service:

```
<div class="col-3" *ngFor="let product of productList">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item clearfix" [productItem]="product" (click)="onAddToCheckoutList()">
    <span class="pull-left">
                        <img 
                        style ="height: 72px;"
                        [src]="product.imagePath"
                        alt="{{ product.name }}" >
                    </span>
    <div class="productName">
      <p> <b> {{product.name}}  </b> <br> Price: €{{product.price}}</p>
    </div>

  </a>
</div>
```

To give you a little example of what the application looks like, I have added the following screenshot:

Comment: Can you show the code listening to `getMsg()` too please ?

Comment: There's nothing listening to getMsg() at this moment, I'm just trying to log the data in the pressed anchor to the console at this moment. I've added code to the edit of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The click handler needs to have the `product` passed in as an argument:

```html
(click)="onAddToCheckoutList(product)"
```

In your component class the method should now look like the following to make use of the new argument:

```js
onAddToCheckoutList(product){
  this.msg.sendMsg(product)
}
```

Unless you have some other functionality that isn't displayed in the question you probably don't need `@Input() productItem: Product` anymore either.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change 2 way binding `[(...)]`:

```
<div class="col-3"  *ngFor="let product of productList">
                <a href="#" 
                class="list-group-item clearfix" 
                [(productItem)]="product"
                (click)="onAddToCheckoutList()"
                >
                    <span class="pull-left">
                        <img 
                        style ="height: 72px;"
                        [src]="product.imagePath"
                        alt="{{ product.name }}" >
                    </span>
                    <div class="productName">
                        <p> <b> {{product.name}}  </b> <br>  Price: €{{product.price}}</p>
                    </div>  
                    
                </a>  
            </div>
```

But with this way, your `productItem` will not choose by clicking and always the last item in `productList`

You have to edit your logic code like this way. When you choose any item this item will pass into `onAddToCheckoutList()` and you will call function add item to itemList in MessengerService:

In `html` file:

```
<div class="col-3"  *ngFor="let product of productList">
                <a href="#" 
                class="list-group-item clearfix" 
                (click)="onAddToCheckoutList(product)"
                >
                    <span class="pull-left">
                        <img 
                        style ="height: 72px;"
                        [src]="product.imagePath"
                        alt="{{ product.name }}" >
                    </span>
                    <div class="productName">
                        <p> <b> {{product.name}}  </b> <br>  Price: €{{product.price}}</p>
                    </div>  

                </a>  
            </div>
```

In `.ts` file:

```
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {


productList: Product[] = [];

@Input() productItem: Product

  constructor(private productService: ProductService, private msg: MessengerService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.productList = this.productService.getProducts()
  } 

  onAddToCheckoutList(productItem){
    this.msg.sendMsg(productItem)
  }
}
```